# Summing up numbers in a defaultdict(list)

Tags: python, python-2.7, sum, iteration

I've been experimenting trying to get this to work and I've exhausted every idea and web search. Nothing seems to do the trick. I need to `sum` numbers in a `defaultdict(list)` and i just need the final result but no matter what i do i can only get to the final result by iterating and returning all sums adding up to the final. What I've been trying generally,

```
d = { key : [1,2,3] }
running_total = 0

#Iterate values
for value in d.itervalues:
  #iterate through list inside value
  for x in value:       
    running_total += x
    print running_total
```

The result is :
`1`,`3`,`6`
I understand its doing this because its iterating through the for loop. What i dont get is how else can i get to each of these list values without using a loop? Or is there some sort of method iv'e overlooked?

To be clear i just want the final number returned e.g. `6`

**EDIT** I neglected a huge factor , the items in the list are timedealta objects so i have to use `.seconds` to make them into integers for adding. The solutions below make sense and I've tried similar but trying to throw in the `.seconds` conversion in the sum statement throws an error.

`d = { key : [timedelta_Obj1,timedelta_Obj2,timedelta_Obj3] }`

Comment: What's the problem? Do you just want to print out the final result instead of all the intermediate results (just move the print statement outside of the loop)? Or do you want to avoid the for loop altogether?

Comment: Your question is poorly asked. It has almost nothing to do with `defaultdict(list)` and the sample code is incorrect and improperly indented -- even with your EDIT...

Comment: @martineau It's not improperly indented QQ

Comment: If you wanted a single total for the whole dictionary, the `print` statement shouldn't have been in nested in the `for` loops -- so the indentation is semantically incorrect.

Comment: Sorry, your statement was poorly delivered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work for you:

```
sum(td.seconds for sublist in d.itervalues() for td in sublist)
```

Comment: Surprisingly to me , this worked. I was expecting it to say `td` was undefined but it didn't. To be clear, sublist here is a arbitrary string?

Comment: Yes it is. It's the same as writing those statements in different lines. You would start with `for sublist in d.itervalues():` and continue on the next line with `for td in sublist:`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach:

```
from datetime import timedelta as TD

d = {'foo' : [TD(seconds=1), TD(seconds=2), TD(seconds=3)],
     'bar' : [TD(seconds=4), TD(seconds=5), TD(seconds=6), TD(seconds=7)],
     'baz' : [TD(seconds=8)]}

print sum(sum(td.seconds for td in values) for values in d.itervalues())
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just `sum` each of the lists in the dictionary, then take one final `sum` of the returned list.

```
>>> d = {'foo' : [1,2,3], 'bar' : [4,5,6,7], 'foobar' : [10]}

# sum each value in the dictionary
>>> [sum(d[i]) for i in d]
[10, 6, 22]

# sum each of the sums in the list
>>> sum([sum(d[i]) for i in d])
38
```

Comment: This would work except i need to do a `.seconds` conversion on each item in the list. See edit please , i apologize.

Comment: @Cyber: just an FYI, you don't need to explicitly make a list when you do the sum. Rather, one can do the following: `sum(sum(v) for k, v in d.items())`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to iterate or to use comprehensions you can use this:

```
d = {'1': [1, 2, 3], '2': [3, 4, 5], '3': [5], '4': [6, 7]}

print(sum(map(sum, d.values())))
```

If you use Python 2 and your dict has a lot of keys it's better you use `imap` (from `itertools`) and `itervalues`

```
from itertools import imap

print sum(imap(sum, d.itervalues()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question was how to get the value "without using a loop". Well, you can't. But there is one thing you can do: use the high performance [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html).

If you use [`chain`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) you won't have an explicit loop in your code. `chain` manages that for you.

```
>>> data = {'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [10, 20], 'c': [100]}
>>> import itertools
>>> sum(itertools.chain.from_iterable(data.itervalues()))
136
```

If you have [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) objects you can use the same recipe.

```
>>> data = {'a': [timedelta(minutes=1), 
                  timedelta(minutes=2), 
                  timedelta(minutes=3)], 
            'b': [timedelta(minutes=10), 
                  timedelta(minutes=20)], 
            'c': [timedelta(minutes=100)]}
>>> sum(td.seconds for td in itertools.chain.from_iterable(data.itervalues()))
8160
```